# Trying to understand inclusion.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let $Y_n$ and $Y$ two random variable.

I want to understand why $\{\lvert 1/Y_n- 1/Y \rvert \ > \epsilon \}\subseteq \{Y<2\delta\} \cup\{\lvert Y_n-Y \rvert > \delta \} \cup \{ \lvert Y_n - Y \rvert > \epsilon \delta^2 \}$ holds for any $\epsilon >0$  and $\delta>0$.

I completely stuck, any help appreciated.

Comment: There is something missing in the first term $\{\lvert 1/Y_n- 1/Y \rvert \}$. It should be for example $\{\lvert 1/Y_n- 1/Y \rvert > \epsilon\}$...otherwise, it is inhomogeneous compared to other terms...

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I fixed it. @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion translates into the statement:

> If $\left| \frac{1}{Y_N} - \frac{1}{Y} \right| > \epsilon$ then either $Y < 2\delta$ or $\left| Y_n - Y \right| > \delta$ or $\left| Y_n - Y \right| > \epsilon \delta^2$

To prove this, let's assume that the following hold:

- $\left| \frac{1}{Y_N} - \frac{1}{Y} \right| > \epsilon$
- $\left| Y_n - Y \right| \leq \epsilon \delta^2$
- $\left| Y_n - Y \right| \leq \delta$

We want to prove that $Y < 2\delta$.

Rewrite the first condition as:
$$\frac{\left|Y - Y_n\right|}{\left|Y_n Y\right|} > \epsilon$$

Including the second condition, we get:
$$\epsilon < \frac{\left|Y - Y_n\right|}{\left|Y_n Y\right|} \leq \frac{\epsilon \delta^2}{\left|Y_n Y\right|}$$

Rearranging, this gives:
$$\left|Y_n Y\right| < \delta^2$$

But the third condition implies $Y_n \geq Y - \delta$ which gives:
$$\delta^2 > \left|Y_n Y\right| \geq Y^2 - \delta Y = \left(Y - \frac{\delta}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{\delta^2}{4}$$

Rearranging, we get:
$$\left(Y - \frac{\delta}{2}\right)^2 < \frac{5}{4}\delta^2$$

Since $\delta > 0$:
$$Y < \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\delta < 2\delta$$

as desired.